# Drive mappings not visible in "net use" or "subst", what kind of drive mappings are they?

Tags: wmic, mapped-drive, net-use, subst

A customer is using `ExpanDrive` for creating network drives. As a result the commands `net use` and `subst` don't give any results.

However the command `wmic logicaldisk` reveals the mentioned drive mappings to be of type `Network Connection`.

What kind of drive mappings are those? What can be done using such kind of drive mappings and what not? (Which Windows features)

Additionally, the command `net use` gave as an answer "New connections will be remembered". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The net use message "New connections will be remembered"
is explained
[by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms847874.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
as :

> The connections that you have at the end of this session will be remembered and, if possible, restored the next time you log on.

This is just an informative message.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpanDrive) Wikipedia page:

> ExpanDrive uses a custom [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) implementation as its file system implementation layer on the Mac and Windows

This would explain why `net use` doesn't show them, since it only shows [SMB/CIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) mappings.

What can be done with those kind of mappings is pretty much up to the implementation. The client programs just sees a disk that it can read and write to. The implementation decides how it handles it. To make it responsive, it would most likely use some kind of caching, otherwise the client software would hang while the data was uploaded.